# Did St. Paul ever claim prophethood?

Tags: new-testament, paul-apostle, prophets

Much of Christianity is based on St. Paul's writings.  Did Saul of Tarsus ever claim to be a prophet of God anywhere in the new testament?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Comment: In Christianity, to be a prophet is not the only way to have an influence, it's a misconception of yours. The same thing in Islam for instance. See for instance the sahabas, were they prophets? Were they words influent as reporters or commenters? Who gathered the hadiths?

Comment: And second misconception "Much of Christianity is based on St Paul", you forgot all the rest. It's the same thing if I say Islam is based on Al Tabari, it makes no sense. You should study a bit more.

Comment: @Quidam The significant difference is fallibility in their sayings and teachings.  A prophet of God by definition is a messenger of God so any knowledge conveyed is transported directly from God to the messenger to us, therefore infallible message.  If the person is not a messenger of God, then his teachings are not directly from God and therefore fallible.

Comment: You confuse everything. Paul didn't bring new teachings, he gave his opinion, that's all. You should study a bit Christianity, because you doesn't seem to understand well basics. No offense.

Comment: @Quidam  So you are saying that St. Paul really has no divine authority, therefore his letters, Acts written by Luke, and Hebrews which taken together account for over 60% of the new testament are just opinions?

Comment: He has a divine authority as an apostle. Sorry, but I'm under the impression you didn't read the Gospel and never studied it. Where is your "60%" comes? (That's completely crazy oO)

Comment: Reply to this question, and I'll be glad to explain you and gives you basic knowledge about it, but first I need your answer: Do you think hadiths are "just opinions"?

Comment: @Quidam  Yes, I have read the new testament.  The gospels (Mark, Matthew, Luke, and John) are about 40% of it.  Not all historians accept Paul as an Apostle.  He never met Yeshua (pbuh), he is complicit in  the killing of Stephan,  and there are documented lies in his letters, particularly in Galatians.  I am not expert but hadiths are gatherings of the sayings and deeds of the prophet Muhammed (pbuh) some generations removed from the actual witnesses.  Depending on the character of the witnesses and narrators, the authenticity is ranked.  Its impossible to filter out all bias and opinion.

Comment: Reading and understanding are 2 different things, and I repeat you, you didn't understand the basics of Christianity. It's like a guy who had read once the Quran and thinks he understands what is Islam. There's little room here to teach you the basics, you should use the chat for this, because the comments will be flooded very quickly. Why don't you reply to my question. Do you think hadiths are "just opinions"?

Comment: Are you talking about theologians or historians? Because many historians think Muhammed never existed, so are we talking about the perception of the Christian theologian about their own religion, or about historians that you don't mention. Be precise.

Comment: @Quidam OK theologians.  I cannot adequately answer here due to limited space.  I will put up an alternate question and we can reply back and forth.  In the meantime please see this link re Paul's lies:

Comment: http://www.judaismvschristianity.com/paula.htm        Muhammed (pbuh) never existed?  Are you referring to historians of alternative facts:) ?   Paul is not the only "Apostle" who lied.  We all know Peter lied 3 times saying he didn't know Yeshua (pbuh).  You only need evidence of 1 lie to invalidate divine authority.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58714/discussion-between-lunar-or-lunacy-explorer-and-quidam).

Comment: Yes, it's the right place.

Answer (score 7):

Paul did not explicitly claim to be a Prophet although there were occasions where he acted as one (cf. [Acts 13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts%2013&version=NIV) & [Acts 27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts%2027&version=NIV)), however he did claim  to be personally called as an ***[Apostle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostles)*** by the risen Christ Jesus.

The Apostles were specifically set apart by Jesus and given authority to teach and are generally considered by Christians to have either equivalent or greater authority to Prophets in regard to their writings:

> Consequently, you are no longer foreigners and strangers, but fellow citizens with God’s people and also members of his household, built on the foundation of the apostles and prophets, with Christ Jesus himself as the chief cornerstone. [Ephesians 2:19-20 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%202&version=NIV)
>
> And God has placed in the church first of all apostles, second prophets, third teachers, then miracles, then gifts of healing, of helping, of guidance, and of different kinds of tongues. - [1 Corinthians 12:28 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2012:28&version=NIV)

Answer (score 4):

Paul was an apostle, but never claimed to be a prophet of the Old Testament variety.  But he did claim to prophecy in the New Testament variety, which is the gift of prophecy.  Two different offices/manifestations.
Romans 12:6

> Having then gifts differing according to the grace that is given to
>   us, whether prophecy, let us prophesy according to the proportion of
>   faith;

1 Cor. 13:2

> And though I have the gift of prophecy, and understand all mysteries,
>   and all knowledge; and though I have all faith, so that I could remove
>   mountains, and have not charity, I am nothing.

1 Cor. 13:9

> For we know in part, and we prophesy in part.

1 Cor. 14:3

> But he that prophesieth speaketh unto men to edification, and
>   exhortation, and comfort.

The differences between an OT prophet and a NT prophet are many.  For examples, the authentic OT prophet spoke as God directed (thus sayeth the LORD), while the NT believer covets the gift of prophecy.  They judged prophetic veracity by results (came true, didn't lead away from the true God).  We judge against Scripture and Spirit spiritually.  They prophesied of what was to come (primarily Christ).  We prophesy to edify, exhort, comfort in Christ.

Comment: A brief description of the difference between OT prophesy and NT prophesy would nicely complete this answer.

Comment: In 1Cor 13:2, "*I have the gift of prophecy*" is not Paul claiming that he is a prophet.  If it were, then he would also be claiming to "*have not charity*".

Comment: The 1 Cor 13 quotes are Paul using a rhetorical device. If you claim it is a factual statement about himself you also have to say that he is claiming he "has not charity", which is obviously not true. The others are collective statements. "We prophesy: does not necessarily mean everyone does. "We Americans go to Canada frequently" does not mean every American goes to Canada.

Comment: @RayButterworth  I agree and that's what I said.  Paul wasn't claiming to be a prophet like an OT prophet, but rather to have the gift of prophecy.  And yes not all believers have that particular gift.

Comment: In 1Cor 13:2, "*I have the gift of prophecy*" is not Paul claiming that he has the gift of prophecy.  It it were, then he would also be claiming to "*have not charity*".